# How to enable A2DP sink functionality in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, bluetooth, a2dp

I'm developing a customized embedded device which uses *Gingerbread 2.3.4* as an OS.
Now the device should be able to play audio streaming from other **A2DP**-enabled devices such as iPhone or other Android devices. I know that the Gingerbread includes `Bluez` stack 4.69 which is capable of A2DP sink functionality. However, I doubt that Android exposes these APIs.

Do you have any ideas how I can achieve this functionality? Since I'm not developing a generic Android App, any kinds of non-standard method will be appreciated. I think the `Bluez` stack can be directly accessed through DBus interface even in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Bluez can support A2DP sink. 
but Android framework doesn't enable this profile.

you may implement the Bluetooth device path using hard-code practice

Comment: So do you mean that you need to use the NDK for this? Or is there a way to enable the A2DP bluetooth sink?

Comment: It depends on your application. When looking through the specification about Bluetooth API of Android framework clearly,
it requires the Android OS to be Android 3.0 HONEYCOMB  or above.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.html

But if you want your application to support these features for Froyo , Gingerbread, hard-code  practice seems to be the solution