# Activate A2DP Sink profile via application in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-5.0-lollipop, a2dp

I wanted to know if it is possible to activate the Sink profile of A2DP in an Android application ? I already saw this SO question ([How to enable A2DP sink functionality in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180895/how-to-enable-a2dp-sink-functionality-in-android)), but it is pretty old, and apparently the sink profile is implemented in Lollipop.

How do I do it ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104611/how-to-modify-androids-bluetooth-stack-to-enable-a2dp-sink/25545427#25545427.
You can get a solution.